# How to add/remove keys/indices of PostgreSQL jsonb dictionaries/arrays?

Tags: json, postgresql, dictionary, merge, jsonb

There is tables with JSON data lists and dictionaries:

Something like this:

```
[1, 34, 566]
```

and

```
{"outer1": 34, "outer2": {"inner1": "blabla", "inner2": "blabla"}}
```

I need edit this jsonb objects inside tables using simple operations like a adding/removing by key and by value in lists.

Are there any quick solutions for this?

Besides also if the target data will be placed in internal JSON entry?

```
{"data": [1, 34, 566]}
```

and

```
{"data": {"outer1": 34, "outer2": {"inner1": "blabla", "inner2": "blabla"}}}
```

Whether the problem will complicated?

Maybe to add new values/keys in JSONB objects I can use `||` operator for merging data. But is this operation slow?

Comment: You can remove keys using the `-` operator and add them using `||` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html what exactly is your question? How should the JSON look like afterwards?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name for example
In [3, 56, 23, 67, 32] i need remove third index and got [3, 56, 67, 32]
Or in {"a": 1, "b": 2} i need remove key "b": {"a": 1}
How be look SQL query?
Also interesting about nested in outer container how the query will be differ? (If data will be placed in {"data": [...]}

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name also I need replace values in list:
before: `[3, 4, 5]`
after: `[3, 5, 5]`

operation like `a[1] = 5`